# aws certified developer exam result

Tags: amazon-web-services

I recently did an AWS exam (certified developer-associate). As you may know, the scoring range is between 100 to 1000, and the minimum score to pass the exam is 720.

Unfortunately I scored 615 points, which means I did not pass the exam. AWS e-mailed me to inform my score. In this e-mail there is no no transcription/percentage of each part of the test. This means I am not able to see on which topics I need to study more to pass my next exam.

Is there any person here who took this exam? If so, could you please tell me how I can understand how many questions I needed to answer more to pass this exam?

Answer (score -1):

The total exam consists of 65 questions. With a passing rate of 72% (720/1000), this amounts to approximately 47 questions (65 * 0.72).

A score of 615 means you had about 40 questions right (65 * 0.615). This means you had to correctly answer about 7 questions more to pass the exam. This is an assumption, as AWS may change the passing rate over time.

615 is not too bad, I would suggest you take some more practice exams and focus on the topics that need more attention according to those tests. To be certain I would make the real exam if you score about 80% on practice exams.

Comment: @Majid I hope you pass your next attempt! Try acloud.guru, they have nice practice exams and lectures.

Comment: Where ca I get legit practice tests?

Comment: Your result score is a scaled score.  It is not a percentage.

Comment: So what? I made an illustration to answer the question, which is totally correct. I don't see what is wrong with this answer. It remains a best guess because AWS never shares transcripts of the actual results.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/training-and-certification/demystifying-your-aws-certification-exam-score/